# Parsing exception in xtext grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, xtext

I have create xtext grammar(see it bellow) but when I run eclipse I have following exception.

> required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'IPADDR_eth0'

I know that problem is probably in the grammar, but don't know where.

So, where I'm wrong?

Regards,

```
grammar com.iamsoft.net.Validate with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate validate "http://www.iamsoft.com/net/Validate"

Model:
    netDescription+=DescriptionPair+;

DescriptionPair:
    ipaddr | netmask | speed | mtu | tso | gateway |  router | subnet | no_vlans | vlan;

 vlan:
    'VLAN_' name=ID '='
    value=IntList;

IntList:
    valueList+=INT+ | '"' valueList+=INT+ '"';

IPAddrList:
    ipNum1=INT '.' ipNum2=INT '.' ipNum3=INT '.' ipNum4=INT;

//List of numbers with 3 digit
 no_vlans:
    'NO_VLANS_' name=ID '=' list+=IntList;

subnet:
    'SUBNET_' name=ID '=' list+=IPWithQuotes;

router:
    'ROUTER_' name=ID '=' list+=IPWithQuotes;

gateway:
    'GATEWAY_' name=ID '=' list+=IPWithQuotes;

mtu:
    'MTU_' name=ID '=' val=IntWithQuotes;

tso:
    'TSO_' name=ID '=' '"' value=ON_OFF '"';

terminal ON_OFF:
    'on' | 'off';

netmask:
    'NETMASK_' name=ID '=' list+=IPWithQuotes;

speed:
    'SPEED_' name=ID '=' value=IntWithQuotes;

ipaddr:
    'IPADDR_' name=ID '=' list+=IPWithQuotes;

IPWithQuotes:
    IPAddrList | '"' IPAddrList '"';

IntWithQuotes:
    value=INT | '"' value=INT '"';
```

Comment: Sorry, my parsed string is :IPADDR_eth0="10.170.53.101"

Comment: can feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your IPADDR_eth0 is parsed a ID not as keyword followed by an ID

maybe it helps to change the ID rule

```
terminal ID : '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
```